# Aws Step function parallel states

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, parallel-processing, aws-step-functions

When the parallel states of a step function complete, assuming they both produce arrays of values, will the order be guaranteed in the final output, and is there any way to split it such that I know which set of values came from one parallel task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html

I was just exploring this, and based off the example in the link above, the resulting array from the parallel task is ordered by the branch configuration order.

The input to the step function is `[ 3, 2 ]` and the first defined branch of the parallel task adds the two numbers, and the second subtracts the two numbers.

The output from the Parallel task is `[ 5, 1 ]`, i.e. `[ 3+2, 3-2 ]`, therefore ordering the results by branch configuration order.

Comment: Thanks Daryl, I also read a blog post that says that if they both output lists, They would be accessible with output[0] and output[1] , instead of outputting one large lists, which is what I needed

Comment: You could define another task that combines both lists after the parallel task completes, i.e. some Lambda function